# Devise case insensitive email when login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using postgresql
Devise stores emails in db with downcase:
config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

But when i login with uppercased email - i got error that email is wrong.
I find solition for this, but this have 1 trouble:

```
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions = {})
    # Allow to log in with case insensitive email
    conditions[:email].downcase!
end
```

1) When I try to logged in with wrong uppercased email I got error and my email with downcase. (logged with AAA@bbb.CCC, got aaa@bbb.ccc, but i need to show AAA@bbb.CCC). How can I change this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was really simple. What you need is just copy params hash and change email in this hash when login, but when user got exception - we just return original hash with entered params

```
def self.find_for_authentication(conditions = {})
  # Allow to log in with case insensitive email
  new_hash = conditions.dup
  new_hash[:email] = conditions[:email].downcase
  where(new_hash).first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get you but you should be able to access the original email
you supplied by

conditions[:email]

Or once logged in you could access the email of the logged in user via
self.email.

Let me know if this helps